# cakephp3 validation before save entity

Tags: validation, cakephp, orm, cakephp-3.0

How can I validate my entity before save? After insert data from form using patchEnity method getErrors returned errors because entity setter wasn't use.

```
//my entity
...
protected function _setSlug($value)
{
    return Text::slug($this->_properties['field_name']);
}

//controller
$data = $this->request->getData();
$contentData = $mainTable->newEntity();
$contentData = $mainTable->patchEntity($contentData, $data, 
['validate' => 'validatorName']);

pr($contentData);
```

When I debug my $contentData there is no data about field 'slug'. If I'll comment out entity setter, the slug property will appear.

Is there any solution to validate enity after using patchEntity of entity with setters ?

Comment: Is there a slug field in the data you are posting to this? What does `$this->_properties['field_name']` have in it?

Comment: are you sending `slug` in `$data` ?